# How do you iterate through a gzipped carriage-return file using python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gzip

I have to use python 2.7 because I'm using the boto library and boto3 is experimental. I need to read a file that is gzipped and lines are terminated by carriage returns. Using [python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/gzip.html#gzip.open) It seems you can just specify the newline variable in gzip.open. What would be the cleanest and still efficient way to do this in python 2.7.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could try `io` module to read the gzipped file as text line by line with universal newlines support:

```
import gzip
import io

with io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(gzip.open(filename))) as file:
    for line in file:
        print line,
```

Comment: io.TextIOWrapper(io.BufferedReader(gzip.open(filePath)), encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') even supports encoding and error handling. Thx!

Comment: Wrapping the `GzipFile` with `BufferedReader` is what really makes this work! Thank you so much, I had been stuck trying to get `readlines()` to work on just a `TextIOWrapper`!